# Error when closing window

Tags: web, kendo-ui

I have the following code for a window:

```
<div class="k-rtl">
<kendo:window name="userRegWindow" title="User Register" content="${userRegUrl}" draggable="true" resizable="false" width="600" close="onClose" visible="false">
    <kendo:window-animation>
        <kendo:window-animation-open effects="zoom:in"/>
        <kendo:window-animation-close effects="zoom:out"/>
    </kendo:window-animation>
</kendo:window> 
</div>

    <script>
            function onClose(){
                alert("Closing User");
            }

    </script>   
    <style>
    .k-rtl {
             font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
             font-size: 12px;

           }
   </style>
```

The window opens without any problem but when I try to close it by clicking on [X] button I got the following error on chrome:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined kendo.web.min.js:26**

### And on Firefox I got this:

```
[15:05:13.499] TypeError: i is undefined @ http://localhost:8080/Cerberus2_0/resources/js/kendo.web.min.js:26
```

Does anybody knows what is happening?

Thanks
Flavio

Comment: Where are you defining content="${userRegUrl}" ?

Answer (score 1):

One a reason could be that you use css class k-window for some div on the page. 
[You may look more info](http://www.telerik.com/forums/multiple-use-k-window)

Answer (score 0):

For those that landed here working with telerik. The issue for me was two open elements with the class "t-window". Remove the class from one of the elements and the close button will work again.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to start from the documentation, your window is not initialized properly or you are not showing this part in your example. Very nice example is here : http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html